# Get git diff between two paths in rust

Tags: rust, diff, libgit2

My goal is to get the `diff` between two source code repositories in rust. With native git command I can do this by performing `git diff [path1] [path2]`. Can I do similar analysis through some crate like [git2](https://crates.io/crates/git2) in rust?

Comment: Do you only need to get the diff between the current contents of the files? Or do you want to get the diff between a certain revision of one file and a certain revision of the other file?

Comment: certain revision.